# ob_start() unexpected behaviour in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have written below code in drupal custom module.

I am getting output in $html but it still printing the output of file.
ie: if string "hello" is there in `custom-report.php` it prints it twice.

```
ob_start();
require_once('templates\custom-report.php');
$html = ob_get_contents();
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `ob_get_clean()` instead of `ob_get_contents()`

You must clean and close your output buffer.

---

**The following will:**

**1.)** Save the contents **2.)** Output them only when you need them.

```
ob_start();
require_once('templates\custom-report.php');
$html = ob_get_clean();
echo $html;
```

---

### `ob_get_contents()`

This will return the buffer contents but does not **erase** the output from the buffer.

---

### `ob_get_clean()`

This will return the buffer contents, **clean** the output buffer, and **end** output buffering.

---

**The code from your question has this undesired effect:**

**1.)** *Output buffer* is saved but left open. **2.)** `echo $html` sends your saved copy of the *output buffer* contents. **3.)** PHP automatically flushes open *output buffer contents* when it reaches the end of a script. So your output is sent a second time.

---

This is a fantastic resource for *Output Buffer* questions:
http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/13/3/0